# Maven: How to manage a shell script as an artefact

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, nexus

I was expecting there to be a really simple answer to this question, but I can't for the life of me find it.

I've got a multi-module Maven application. One of these modules will be used to manage a single shell script (at build time I'll be inserting build numbers). When I've done this I'll need to upload it to Nexus.

If this were a JAR, WAR or even a POM we would tell maven about it by using the `package` directive, as in:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artefact</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

The trouble is there isn't a packaging value for shell scripts.

How are we supposed to upload shell scripts?

Comment: Inserting build number for a build does not really make sense apart from that ... put the script into `src/main/resources` and it will be packaged into a resulting jar file... keep the jar packaging which is the simplest. What I don't understand why do you need that script?

Comment: @khmarbaise - Thanks, but that won't work. It's a launch script, so it can't be deployed inside the JAR which is what would happen if I put it into the `resources` directory. The script prompts the user for the right set of parameters then calls the main JAR. Also, the JAR file names includes the versions, so they can change on each build. This is easy to handle, Maven can do some text substitution to change the names of JARs in the script based on the `${project.version}`. I'd like to treat the script as just another artifact in my multi-module build, hence the question

Comment: If that's the case simple make a separate module put the script into the src/main/resources to get filtering (versions etc.) and it will be published via a jar.. If you need to deploy it separately you can use build-helper-maven-plugin to attach that separately as separate file but who should know that this script exists? So a launch script should be made part of a zip/tar.gz archive which contains everything you need. Interactive script sounds wrong for me (personal opinion). And what do they need to change on each build? What do you need to change? What does this script exactly do?

Comment: @khmarbaise. WRT the launcher script and at the risk of getting off topic, I'm not wild about the interactive script either. However knowing how complex the arguments to the application are I can see why that has become the requirement. The dynamic bit is to determine the version in a line that looks like `java  jar  myJar-VERSION.jar   -all -my -arguments`.

Comment: The question why the call of Java contains the version because the jar file needs to be somewhere which could being solved by creating a tar.get/zip which contains the files without a version ....

Comment: @khmarbaise. WRT the POMs, is there a clean way of managing a shell script in Maven? Wrapping it in a JAR doesn't sound quite right. I'd end up with a manifest which doesn't really make sense. I guess I could shove it into a ZIP using the assembly plugin, but that's a lot of extra hassle for something that should be very simple. I can't imagine I'm the first person to want to do this!

Comment: As to why the Jar is versioned, that's because it needs to fit into a larger system and that's the requirement for all the components. I don't get a choice. Besides, it's trivial to do